# JavaScript: Iterating through multi-dimensional arrays and extracting multiple search values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

**What I want to do:**

Search through a multi-dimensional array using multiple search strings.

**Example of what I am currently doing:**

```
var multiArray = [['Apples and pears', 'tuna salad'],['bananas tuna'],['the colour blue']];

var singleArray = [];

var match_array = [];

// Turn multiple arrays into one big one
    for (var i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {

        for (var x = 0; x < multiArray[i].length; x++) {

            singleArray.push(multiArray[i][x]);
    }
}

// Create a new array from matched strings

function find_match(to_match) {

    for (var i in singleArray) {

        if (singleArray[i].indexOf(to_match)!= -1)

        match_array.push(singleArray[i]);
    }

    return (match_array.length === 0 ? null : match_array);

}

// Find matching terms for match_array
find_match('tuna');
find_match('the');

alert(match_array);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yVYAL/2/)

**Questions:**

1. Obviously this is a cluttered way of doing this. How can this be
   streamlined(i.e. searching the `multiArray` directly and not using
   multiple `find_match` functions)?
2. How can I get only the exact string matches, preferably without breaking up the multi-dimensional array?
3. What are your thoughts about searching through massive
   multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
var multiArray = [['Foo', 'Bar'],['Foo'],['Bar']];

var singleArray = [];

var match_array = [];

// Turn multiple arrays into one big one
for (var i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < multiArray[i].length; x++) {
        singleArray.push(multiArray[i][x]);
    }
}

// Create a new array from matched strings
function find_match(to_match, where_search) {

    for (var j in where_search) {
        if(where_search[j] instanceof Array){
           find_match(to_match, where_search[j]);

        }else{
            for (var i in to_match) {
                if (where_search[j].indexOf(to_match[i]) ==0 && 
                    where_search[j].length == to_match[i].length)
                    match_array.push(where_search[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return (where_search.length === 0 ? null : match_array);

}

// Find matching terms for match_array
find_match(['Foo', 'Bar'],multiArray);

alert(match_array);
```

Comment: When I run this script through JSFiddle it only alerts 'tuna salad'.

Comment: Not quite... now it's alerting 'tuna salad','bananas tuna'

Comment: Do you need to match entire array search inside multi array? Example: multi=[['Foo','Bar'],['Foo'],['Bar']] search ['Foo','Bar'] - return ['Foo','Bar'] ?

Comment: Ideally, using your example, search `['Foo','Bar']` return `['Foo','Bar','Foo','Bar']`

Comment: Try now. **How can this be streamlined(i.e. searching the multiArray directly and not using multiple find_match functions)?** You can add new function to Array. Example: Array.prototype.add = <script>function(foo){this.push(foo)};p=[];p.add("a");p.add("b");p.add("c");alert(p)</script>